# Turn the randomly selected previous images to gray scale

Tags: jquery, css

I have 16 gray-scale images,I need them to select randomly and made them as color images.Like the below code I am doing that.

```
setInterval(function(){

    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 1;
    $(".pnfitem-" + i).css('filter', "grayscale(0%)");
    $(".pnfitem-" + i).css('-webkit-filter', "grayscale(0%)");

},3000);
```

That's working fine too,but now I need to add gray-scale to the previous image when the next image turn to color image.Though these are randomly selected,how can I select the previous image and turn it back to gray-scale image

Comment: When you color an image, add a class '.colored'. You can find it back easily afterwards. Don't forget to remove the class when you go back to gray.

Comment: @Gerard simple and perfect answer.working fine.Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
setInterval(function(){

    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
    $(".pnfitem").removeClass("noGray").eq(i).addClass("noGray");
    
}, 1000);
```

```css
.pnfitem{
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: 0.8s;
}
.noGray{
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
<img class="pnfitem" src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
```